# Нахождение искомый строки более 1 раза

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

1) Пытаюсь сделать поиск в `DataGridView` с помощью операций `LINQ`:

```
var find = UsersDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cells[cbFilterSearch.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString().Contains(tbSearch.Text));

if (find != null)
{
    find.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Раскрашивает только одну строку в красный цвет, хотя нахождений больше. Как исправить?

2) Возможно ли переделать данный код на `LINQ`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < UsersDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
    UsersDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раскрашивает только одну строку в красный цвет по причине того, что Вы берете `FirstOrDefault` - это означает, что в результате получим либо одну строку, либо `null` если элемент не найден (значение по умолчанию `Default`).

Поэтому немного модифицируем Ваш код следующим образом:

```
var indexFilter = cbFilterSearch.SelectedIndex; // вынес для удобства
var findResult = UsersDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => x.Cells[indexFilter].Value.ToString().Contains(tbSearch.Text)).ToList();

// меняем цвет так (по Вашему примеру)
for (int index = 0; index < findResult.Count; index++)
{
    findResult[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

// или меняем цвет вот так (немного удобнее)
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in findResult)
{
   row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Попросту заменили `FirstOrDefault` на `Where(predicate).ToList()` и вместо одного элемента - получили коллекцию элементов, удовлетворяющих условию поиска.

По поводу второго вопроса, можно предложить такой вариант `LINQ`:

```
UsersDataGridView.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White);
```

Преобразуем элемент `Rows` из типа `DataGridViewRowCollection` в список элементов `DataGridViewRow` и в цикле `ForEach` меняем значение `BackColor` у каждого элемента коллекции.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Последний абзац странный. Ты здесь и не меняешь элемент коллекции. Ссылка findResult[index] останется неизменной. Ты меняешь значение поля у объекта.

Comment: @Максим, дополнил ответ `LINQ`, можно переделать, просто `Cast` нужен был.

Answer (score 2):

1. [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) — возвращает первый элемент коллекции или значение по-умолчанию, если коллекция пуста. Для вашей задачи подходящим будет метод [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx) который фильтрует коллекцию по предикату.
2. Можно задать цвет [всем ячейкам сразу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо большое.